# Shellscript `grep` execution not working as in the interactive shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, output

Having to deal with an environment where `ack` and so on is not available nor installable, this command try to limit only relevant files to find string through the C++ project :

```
 grep pattern --color -- /project/path/**/*.*([chCH]|cc|cxx|[ch]pp|py)
```

This does the job. Now to bring a bit more commodity to that, the goal is to put that into a shell script. Let's say it's named `wrapped_grep`. Here is the content of `wrapped_grep`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob # enable advanced pattern matching
grep $1 --color -- /project/path/**/*.*([chCH]|cc|cxx|[ch]pp|py)
```

But trying to launch `wrapped_grep pattern` don't provide any output, even when the equivalent direct grep query does find matches as expected.

What is missing in this script to provide the same result as the direct grep invocation?

Comment: Which shell are you using when entering the command directly?

Comment: Perhaps you need to set shell option `globstar` as well as `extglob`?

Comment: That was the globstar that was missing indeed, thank you steeldriver, please turn your comment into an answer so I can validate it. :)

Comment: @psychoslave done - please see below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extglob` shell option enables the `*([chCH]|cc|cxx|[ch]pp|py)` part of your expression, but the `**/` part requires the `globstar` option

> ```
>           globstar
>                   If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion con‐
>                   text  will  match all files and zero or more directories
>                   and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a  /,
>                   only directories and subdirectories match.
> ```

So you likely need

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
```